# How to change application font size in brackets

Tags: font-size, adobe-brackets

How to change the application font size in brackets?

I want to change the font size of the side menu, menu bar, bottom bar and title bars of the editor which is very small. [ctrl] + [+] will only change the editor font size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **Temporary fix**

> **File -> Extension Manager -> search for "UI too small"** and add an extension to make the font larger.

Find more details on - https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/8059.
Work is in progress to fix this issue and it will be fixed in the next release. Track the progress - https://trello.com/c/WRhZ0xvj/969-high-dpi-support-on-windows-and-linux.

---

This has worked out for some people in my case the UI is not much responsive. Therefore waiting for the new release.

Answer (score 1):

As Shanika suggested, "UI too small" allows you to control the size of the side/Menu fontSize, but it doesn't answer to Ctr + or -.

Nevertheless, you can still do it manually by changing directly the main.js under `Brackets->extensions->user->ui-too-small->main.js` Or by clicking on the menu Help then Show Extensions Folder, and click on main.js under user/ui-too-small.

Open main.js and change the fontSize you want in `font-size: 22px`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setting for the [ui-too-small](https://github.com/1beb/ui-too-small) plugin For windows trough:
Help > Show Extensions Folder > Navigate to user > Navigate to ui too small > open main.js

I personally like the following settings (Material design):

```
    define(function (require, exports, module) {
        "use strict";

    ExtensionUtils.addEmbeddedStyleSheet("#sidebar *, #main-toolbar *, #titlebar *, #problems-panel *,"+
    "#find-in-files-results *, #e4b-main-panel *, #status-bar *,"+
    "#main-toolbar *, #context-menu-bar *, #codehint-menu-bar *,"+
    "#quick-view-container *, #function-hint-container *  { font-size: 16px !important;"+
    " line-height: 30px !important; }"+
    ".sidebar li { min-height: 30px !important;}"+
    ".sidebar-selection, .filetree-selection { min-height: 30px !important; margin-top: 5px;}"+
    ""+".jstree-icon{margin-top:10px !important} .filetree-selection-extension{margin-top: 5px; height: 30px !important;} .jstree-rename-input{ margin-top: 2px !important; height: 30px !important;   padding-bottom: 0px !important;} "
    );
    });
```